# Share Image Alpha value with SharedDefault

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

In my app i set the alpha value of 3 images depending on a context. i would like to pass that alpha value to the apple watch using sharedDefault. And then set the same alpha value to the corresponding image on the watch. I know how to pass a string very well but not with a value . Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code on the main app:

```
            if grandTotalPax <=  90 {
            let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName:"group.birkyboy.CrewStaffingTodayExtension")

            sharedDefaults!.setDouble(1, forKey: "totalfull")
            sharedDefaults!.setDouble(0.3, forKey: "totalmoyen")
            sharedDefaults!.setDouble(0.3, forKey: "totalempty")

            totalFull.alpha = 1
            totalMoyen.alpha = 0.2
            totalEmpty.alpha = 0.2
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure if this answer your question because this seems not clear, since you are doing the correct approach to set values.

If you want to share values between iOS device and Apple Watch, is pretty simple.

First, I assume you already defined `AppGroups` for both targets (device and watch).

Second, you need to get `NSUserDefaults` like this

```
if let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.birkyboy.CrewStaffingTodayExtension") {
  // Do your stuffs here
}
```

Inside `if` block, you can define your values by the same way you are doing.

```
sharedDefaults.setFloat(0.3, "totalempty") // Look I'm using float because is less expensive than double and fits the range alpha values you need.
```

After then, you should save your `NSUserDefaults` like this:

```
if sharedDefaults.synchronize() {
  // syncrhonized succeffully
}
```

Without this action, you shared defaults will never be saved.

At watch, you can grab values easily like this:

```
if let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.birkyboy.CrewStaffingTodayExtension") {
  let alpha: Float = sharedDefaults.floatForKey("totalempty") // if this key does not exist, this will return 0.
}
```

I hope this can help you.